# Return sum of column where max from other column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have this query:

```sql
select
    Customer as Customer,
    siteId,
    pos,
    week,
    sum(Inventory) as totalInventory,
    sum(Amount) as totalAmount
from Uploads
WHERE Year = 2022
group by Customer, week, siteId, pos;
```

and returns something like this:

| Customer | siteId | pos | week | totalInventory | totalAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer A | id00A1 | posA1 | 1 | 67 | 50 |
| customer A | id00A2 | posA2 | 1 | 75 | 45 |
| customer A | id00A3 | posA3 | 1 | 98 | 88 |
| customer B | id00B1 | posB1 | 1 | 67 | 50 |
| customer C | id00C1 | posC1 | 1 | 67 | 50 |
| customer C | id00C2 | posC2 | 1 | 75 | 45 |
| customer B | id00B1 | posB1 | 2 | 67 | 50 |
| customer C | id00C1 | posC1 | 2 | 67 | 50 |
| customer C | id00C2 | posC2 | 2 | 75 | 45 |
| customer B | id00B1 | posB1 | 3 | 67 | 50 |

But I want to know the data of the last week depending on the client, not every week. Something like this:

| Customer | siteId | pos | week | totalInventory | totalAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer A | id00A1 | posA1 | 1 | 67 | 50 |
| customer A | id00A2 | posA2 | 1 | 75 | 45 |
| customer A | id00A3 | posA3 | 1 | 98 | 88 |
| customer C | id00C1 | posC1 | 2 | 67 | 50 |
| customer C | id00C2 | posC2 | 2 | 75 | 45 |
| customer B | id00B1 | posB1 | 3 | 67 | 50 |

What is missing from my query?

I tried the following queries:

```sql
select
    Customer as Customer,
    siteId,
    pos,
    max(week),
    sum(Inventory) as totalInventory,
    sum(Amount) as totalAmount
from Uploads
WHERE Year = 2022
group by Customer, week, siteId, pos;
```

```sql
select
    Customer as Customer,
    siteId,
    pos,
    max(week),
    sum(Inventory) as totalInventory,
    sum(Amount) as totalAmount
from Uploads
WHERE Year = 2022
group by Customer, week, siteId, pos
having max(week);
```

But still having the same results.

create table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Uploads ( 
   id int, 
   Year int, 
   Week int, 
   Division varchar(255), 
   ProductGroupID varchar(255), 
   Country varchar(255), 
   Customer varchar(255), 
   POS varchar(255), 
   SiteID varchar(255), 
   Brand varchar(255), 
   Product varchar(255), 
   Inventory int NOT NULL, 
   SoldUnits int NOT NULL, 
   Amount float NOT NULL )
```

Comment: run `show create table Uploads` and let us have the definition and also some sample data covering a few weeks

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Uploads` (
  `id` int,
  `Year` int,
  `Week` int,
  `Division` varchar(255),
  `ProductGroupID` varchar(255),
  `Country` varchar(255),
  `Costumer` varchar(255),
  `POS` varchar(255),
  `SiteID` varchar(255),
  `Brand` varchar(255),
  `Product` varchar(255),
  `Inventory` int NOT NULL,
  `SoldUnits` int NOT NULL,
  `Amount` float NOT NULL
)

Comment: info like above can be done using [edit] in the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a sub-query to find the latest week for each customer.

```
select
    c Customer,
    SiteId,
    pos,
    Week,
    sum(inventory) TotalInventory,
    sum(amount) TotalAmount
from 
    (select
         customer c,
         year y,
         max(week) w
     from 
         Uploads
     where 
         year = 2022
     group by customer) lastWeek
join 
    Uploads on c = customer
            and y = year and w = week
group by
    c, SiteId, pos, week
```

| Customer | SiteId | pos | Week | TotalInventory | TotalAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer A | 00A1 | posA1 | 1 | 67 | 50 |
| customer A | 00A2 | posA2 | 1 | 75 | 45 |
| customer A | 00A3 | posA3 | 1 | 98 | 88 |
| customer B | 00B1 | posB1 | 3 | 67 | 50 |
| customer C | 00C1 | posC1 | 2 | 67 | 50 |
| customer C | 00C2 | posC2 | 2 | 75 | 45 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=51b69e88912749588d362a7fb5877cfb)*